# Checkboxes and other fields are not being submitted to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

Some of my text fields in all of the checkboxes in my html form are not being submitted to MySQL database.  Most of the fields like name and email go through, but I can't seem to figure out why some don't work.  Here is the html code:

```
<form action="js/phpsubmit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Form" id="Form">
    <p>
    <table width="978" height="373" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><label for="name">Full Name</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td width="23%"><label for="email">Email</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td width="57%"><label for="phone">Phone #</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="address">Address</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td width="23%"><label for="city">City</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td width="57%"><label for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="ZipCode" id="ZipCode" />
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Age">Age</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="Age" id="Age" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="Gender">Gender</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="Gender" id="Gender" />
          &nbsp;</td>
        <td><label for="DOB">DOB(mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB" />
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><label for="CurrentMedications">Current Medications</label>
          <br />
          <textarea name="CurrentMedications" id="CurrentMedications" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
        <td><label for="CurrentMedicalConditions">Current Medical Conditions</label>
          <br />
          <textarea name="CurrentMedicalConditions" id="CurrentMedicalConditions" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><label for="Comments">Comments</label>
          <br />
          <textarea name="Comments" id="Comments" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
        <tr><td><br /></td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><label for="BP">BP</label>
          <input name="BP" type="text" id="BP" size="3" />
          <label for="P">P</label>
          <input name="P" type="text" id="P" size="3" />
          <label for="Glu">Glu</label>
          <input name="Glu" type="text" id="Glu" size="3" />
          <label for="TC">TC</label>
          <input name="TC" type="text" id="TC" size="3" />
          <label for="W">W</label>
          <input name="W" type="text" id="W" size="3" />
          <label for="H">H</label>
          <input name="H" type="text" id="H" size="3" />
          <label for="BMI">BMI</label>
          <input name="BMI" type="text" id="BMI" size="3" />
          <label for="HBA1C">HBA1C</label>
          <input name="HBA1C" type="text" id="HBA1C" size="3" />
          <label for="Other">Other</label>
          <input name="Other" type="text" id="Other" size="7" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><table width="934">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="4"><p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>What Studies are you Interested in?</p></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="260"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Acne"  />
                  Acne</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Constipation"  />
                  Constipation</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Hepatitis"  />
                  Hepatitis</label></td>
              <td width="203"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Rheumatoid Arthritis"  />
                  Rheumatoid Arthritis</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Alchohol Addiction"  />
                  Alchohol Addiction</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Contraception"  />
                  Contraception</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="High Blood Pressure"  />
                  High Blood Pressure</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Shingles"  />
                  Shingles</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Allergies"  />
                  Allergies</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Contact Lenses/Solution"  />
                  Contact Lenses/Solution</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="High Cholesterol"  />
                  High Cholesterol</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Sleep Apneal"  />
                  Sleep Apnea</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Ankle Sprain"  />
                  Ankle Sprain</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Cramp during Menses"  />
                  Cramp during Menses</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="High Triglycerides"  />
                  High Triglycerides</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Sleep Disorders/Insomnia"  />
                  Sleep Disorders/Insomnia</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Anxiety"  />
                  Anxiety</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Depression"  />
                  Depression</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="HIV or Aids"  />
                  HIV or Aids</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Smoking Cessation"  />
                  Smoking Cessation</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Asthma"  />
                  Asthma</label></td>
              <td width="242"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Dermatitis" id="checkbox_22" />
                  Dermatitis</label>
                &nbsp;</td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Hot Flashes"  />
                  Hot Flashes</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Tendonitis"  />
                  Tendonitis</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Atrial Fibrillation"  />
                  Atrial Fibrillation(AFIB)</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Diabetes type 1"  />
                  Diabetes type 1</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="HPV"  />
                  HPV Vaccine</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Tinnitius"  />
                  Tinnitius (ringing ears)</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="ADD"  />
                  Attention Deficit Disorder(ADD)</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Diabetes type 2"  />
                  Diabetes type 2</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Irritable Bowel Syndrome"  />
                  Irritable Bowel Syndrome</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="UTI"  />
                  Urinary Tract Infections</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Back Pain"  />
                  Back Pain</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Dibetic Neuropaty"  />
                  Dibetic Neuropathy Pain</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Low Testosterone"  />
                  Low Testosterone</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Vaccine Trials"  />
                  Vaccine Trials in General</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Bipolar"  />
                  Bipolar Disorder</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Diarrhea"  />
                  Diarrhea</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Migraines/headaches"  />
                  Migraines/Headaches</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Yeast infections"  />
                  Yeast Infections</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Breast Pain"  />
                  Breast Pain</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Dry Eye"  />
                  Dry Eye</label></td>
              <td width="209"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Obesity"  />
                  Obesity</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Cancer"  />
                  Cancer</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Endometiosis"  />
                  Endometriosis</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Osteoarthritis"  />
                  Osteoarthritis</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Childhood Vacs"  />
                  Childhood Vaccinations</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Erectile Dysfunction"  />
                  Erectile Dysfunction</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Osteoporosis"  />
                  Osteoporosis</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Chronic Bronchitis"  />
                  Chronic Bronchitis</label></td>
              <td width="242"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Fibromyalgia"  />
                  Fibromyalgia</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Overactive Bladder"  />
                  Overactive Bladder</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Chronic Kidney Disease"  />
                  Chronic Kidney Disease</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Flu"  />
                  Flu/Seasonal Allergies</label></td>
              <td><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Pain Management"  />
                  Pain Management</label></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease"  />
                  Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Healthy Patient Trials"  />
                  Healthy Patient Trials</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Psoriasis"  />
                  Psoriasis</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Cold Sores"  />
                  Cold Sores</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Heartburn"  />
                  Heartburn</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Restless Leg Syndrome"  />
                  Restless Leg Syndrome</label></td>
              <td class="auto-style1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><br /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><br /></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" style="padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #FF9900; font-weight: bold; color: #333333;" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sudies=$_POST['checkbox'];

if(count($studies) > 0)
{
 $studies_string = implode(",", $studies);
}
// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Age']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Gender']);
$dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DOB']);
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Comments']);
$study = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $studies_string);
$medications = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CurrentMedications']);
$conditions = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['CurrentMedicalConditions']);
$bp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['BP']);
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['P']);
$glu = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Glu']);
$tc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['TC']);
$w = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['W']);
$h = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['H']);
$bmi = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['BMI']);
$hba1c = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['HBA1C']);
$ohter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Other']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
$zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ZipCode']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Patients (Name, Phone, Age, Gender, DOB, Comments, InterestedStudies, Email, Address, City, Zipcode, CurrentMedication, CurrentmedicalConditions, BP, P, Glu, TC, W, H, BMI, HBA1C, Other)
VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$age', '$gender', '$dob', '$comments', '$study', '$email', '$address', '$city', '$zipcode', '$medications', '$conditions', '$bp', '$p', '$glue', '$tc', '$w', '$h', '$bmi', '$hba1c', '$other')"; 

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

header('Location: thank-you.html');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: man, that is too much `mysqli_real_escape_string`, use prepared statements instead

Comment: try to change the name `name="checkbox[]"` to `name="someother[]"`

Comment: do var_dump on $_POST.

Comment: You've got two typos that I can see: `$sudies` should be `$studies`, `$ohter` should be `$other`. Before you even mess around with database insertion you should make sure first you have received all user input, using print_r or var_dump.

Comment: It was the typos! Thank you!  This is my first time messing with php/MySQL.  Looks like I need to do more reading, thanks for the advise on print_r/var_dump; as well as prepared statements.

Comment: You need to give checkboxes the same name attribute for each group of options, unless I've misread this and every single checkbox in your code is for the same set of options... Otherwise you're going to end up with a very confusing set of posted data.